# Avoir mal au pied or avoir mal aux pieds?

Tags: vocabulaire

What is correct: j'ai mal au pied or j'ai mal aux pieds? 
Since it can be translated into "I have a foot ache" or "My feet hurt."

Comment: Ça dépend si tu as mal à un pied ou aux deux, tu n'en dis pas assez. Both are correct, depending on what you want to say. I have a footache doesn't tell if one one or both of your feet ache. But we're on the wrong site to discuss this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> J'ai mal au pied.

Veut dire qu'un de mes deux pieds me fait mal. (Just one of my feet hurts)

> J'ai mal aux pieds.

Veut dire que j'ai mal à mes deux pieds. (My feet hurt)

Ceci dit si j'ai mal à un seul pied je dirais plus volontiers :

> Mon pied me fait mal.

Answer (score 1):

What is the question since you answered it already? *Mal au pied* means one foot, *Mal aux pieds* means both feet.